# Non-Standard Composite Relationship in EF Core

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I have a 3rd party database I'm trying to integrate with EF Core and it uses strange composite columns instead of foreign keys. A relationship is defined by a "Parent_Table_Name" and "Parent_Id". They're not keys, just an nchar(20) that contains the table name and an int with the ID in that table respectively. Is there any way I can establish navigation properties between tables if they don't have foreign keys?

The provider is Microsoft SQL Server. Here are CREATE statements that describe the situation.

```
CREATE TABLE [ParentA] (Table_Name nchar(20), Id int)
CREATE TABLE [ParentB] (Table_Name nchar(20), Id int)
CREATE TABLE [ChildC] (Table_Name nchar(20), Id int, Parent_Table_Name nchar(20), Parent_Table_Id int)
```

Here is an image of some sample data given the above tables.

[image: sample data of ParentA, ParentB, and ChildC]

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the table structure you have (`CREATE TABLE` statements) and the sample data you have to show the "pseudo foreign keys" you have. Add several rows to different tables as example data.

Comment: @Progman I've done so.

Answer (score 2):

These are known as a polymorphic associations (feature request [#757](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/757)). There is currently no first-class support for it, but you can work around it:

```cs
class ParentA
{
    public string Table_Name { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ChildC> ChildCs { get; set; }
}

class ParentB
{
    public string Table_Name { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ChildC> ChildCs { get; set; }
}

class ChildC
{
    public string Table_Name { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    public int? ParentA_Id { get; set; }
    public ParentA ParentA { get; set; }
    
    public int? ParentB_Id { get; set; }
    public ParentB ParentB { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
var childrenWithParents = dbContext.ChildCs
    // TODO: You could also create a view in the database
    //       or use ToSqlQuery on modelBuilder
    .FromSql(@"
        SELECT Table_Name,
            Id,
            CASE
                WHEN Parent_Table_Name = 'ParentA'
                    THEN Parent_Table_Id
            END AS ParentA_Id,
            CASE
                WHEN Parent_Table_Name = 'ParentB'
                    THEN Parent_Table_Id
            END AS ParentB_Id
        FROM ChildC")
    .Include(c => c.ParentA)
    .Include(c => c.ParentB)
    .ToList();
```